# Use Require.js for a script with qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, qunit

On my book of Eric Elliot I find these three code but I can not understand like to use them:

**(1)**

```
define(['ch04/amd1', 'ch04/amd2'],
function myModule(amd1, amd2) {
    var testResults = {
        test1: amd1.test(),
        test2: amd2.test()
    },
    // Define a public API for your module:
    api = {
        testResults: function () {
            return testResults;
        }
    };
    return api;
});
```

**(2)**

```
require(['ch04-amd'], function (amd) {
    var results = amd.testResults();
    test('AMD with Require.js', function () {
        equal(results.test1, true,
            'First dependency loaded correctly.');
        equal(results.test2, true,
            'Second dependency loaded correctly.');
    });
});
```

**(3)**

```
if (typeof define === 'function') {
    define([], function () {
        return api;
    });
}
```

I tried to use require.js and I write these codes but it doesn't work:

**javascript\librerie\jquery.js**

**javascript\librerie\qunit.js**

**javascript\librerie\require.js**

**script_libro_eric_elliott.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Utilizzo della libreria Require.js</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script data-main="javascript/moduli" src="javascript/librerie/require.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Utilizzo della libreria Require.js</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript\moduli\script_libro.js**

```
define(['ch04/amd1', 'ch04/amd2'],
function myModule(amd1, amd2) {
    var testResults = {
        test1: amd1.test(),
        test2: amd2.test()
    },
    // Define a public API for your module:
    api = {
        testResults: function () {
            return testResults;
        }
    };
    return api;
});
```

**javascript\moduli\main.js**

```
require(['ch04-amd'], function (amd) {
    var results = amd.testResults();
    test('AMD with Require.js', function () {
        equal(results.test1, console.log(true),
            'First dependency loaded correctly.');
        equal(results.test2, console.log(true),
            'Second dependency loaded correctly.');
    });
});
```

**javascript\configurazione.js**

```
/* global requirejs */
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "javascript/librerie",
    "paths": {
        "moduli": "../moduli"
    },
    "shim": {
        "script_libro": {
            deps: ["jquery", "qunit"]
        }
    }
});
requirejs(["moduli/main"]);
```

I would like to write output strings on console so I edit Eric Elliot's script too. On my console I can only read:

```
Error: Script error for: moduli
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Could you help me, please?

---

**NEW UPDATE**

---

I believe that the problem is in script_libro.js in fact the console find an error only in this file. I send you my new code:

**script_libro_eric_elliott.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Utilizzo della libreria Require.js</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
        <script data-main="javascript/configurazione.js" 
                src="javascript/librerie/require.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Utilizzo della libreria Require.js</div>
        <div id="contenitore"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**javascript\moduli\script_libro.js**

```
define(['jquery', 'qunit'], function myModule(amd1, amd2) {
    var testResults = {
        test1: amd1.test(),
        test2: amd2.test()
    },
    api = {
        testResults: function () {
            return testResults;
        }
    };
    return api;
});
```

**javascript\moduli\main.js**

```
require(['javascript/moduli/script_libro.js'], function (amd) {
    var results = amd.testResults;
    test('AMD with Require.js', function () {
        equal(results.test1, true,
                console.log('First dependency loaded correctly.'));
        equal(results.test2, true,
                console.log('Second dependency loaded correctly.'));
    });
});
```

**javascript\configurazione.js**

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'javascript/librerie',
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    paths: {
        CartellaModuli: '../moduli',
    },
    shim: {
        script_libro: {
            deps: ['qunit', 'jquery']
        }
    }
});
require(['CartellaModuli/main']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data-main should point to a module instead of a directory. Try changing it to `data-main="javascript/moduli/main"`.

That probably won't solve everything since you don't include your configuration in `configurazione.js` anywhere.

Comment: I get this message:

Error: Script error for: moduli/script_libro
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:8:251
Error: Script error for: qunit
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:8:251
Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror require.js:8:251

What I must write in the configurazione.js file?

Comment: You should start with something simpler, like a single module that prints Hello World. No libraries, no extra configuration. Then add to that until it no longer works. Then read requirejs documentation, learn to use your browser's dev tools and then if you have problems you can post a more specific question here.

Comment: Finally I found the mistake but I can not found a solution. I tried to use this library for others problems and I must tell that it works rightly. I don't understand why the author use test1.test(), what does this code? In the console I read "TypeError: amd1.test is not a function" and it is right. What did he mean the author with this code?

Comment: DOWNLOAD HERE:


http://we.tl/ha9JfggYvr


OR:


http://www.filedropper.com/01_3
http://www.filedropper.com/02_4

Comment: Have you found a solution to my problem?